# Regex to extract a string from html page

Tags: regex, testing, jmeter

I have an html response, in which, a particular line is

```
var session_name = '1342100453_3334440619019170';
```

from which, I need to extract `'1342100453_3334440619019170'` and `1342100453_3334440619019170`

Would it be possible to extract in using a regex? I need to reply this parameter in jmeter, but that's a different story.

Comment: Which regular expression flavor would this be? PCRE, Java, .NET, POSIX ...?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @JackManey , I tried ^var session_name, but that would return the whole string. I am new to regex.

Comment: @0xC0000022L It would be Java regex.

Comment: So use a capturing group in your regex. This isn't complicated. Read some regex tutorials, [try something](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and come back if you have a specific question about what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\s*var\s+session_name\s*=\s*'(.*)';\s*$
```

That will capture `'1342100453_3334440619019170'` into the first capturing group. Whatever API you are using should be able to access that value relatively easily.

EDIT: I see you are using Java.

I'm not familiar with any of the regex APIs in Java, although `java.util.regex.Pattern` doesn't look too bad.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: `(.*)` is a greedy pattern, avoid them when possible. Use a negation pattern to restrict the search pattern, like this: `^\s*var\s+session_name\s*=\s*'([^']*)';\s*$`, as your session_name variable will not contain apostrophes.